# Is there a way to increase/decrease casting speed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I need to know if there is a console command to change how fast I cast spells. I know that you can set your walking/running speed and your regen speed with console commands, but is there any way to alter the speed of casting my spells?
I really want to just cast a bunch of ice spear spells at once.

Answer (score 11):

I'm pretty sure there aren't any console commands that can do that. But it's actually surprisingly easy to mod it yourself with the Creation Kit. It's all graphical, you don't need to know any programming or worry about anything complicated.

If you're interested, check out [CreationKit](http://www.creationkit.com/Category:Getting_Started)'s tutorial on how to install it, and create, save, and load your first, blank mod.

Then, in the Object Window, expand Magic, and click Spell. From the list you can select the one you want, and double-click to edit it. It should look like this:

[image: editor window]

Note that by default, "Auto-Calculate" is checked and you'll need to uncheck it, then set your Charge Time down. Then click OK, save, and remember to load it the next time you start your game, and you're done.

**Edit**: While I did try this out and test it myself, there is one possile caveat that I didn't check for. If my suspicions are correct (I'm new to modding, myself), changing this value here probably means that enemies who have this spell can cast it right back at you just as fast. (Edit 2: Be sure to see kotekzot's response about this)

Comment: There should be no reason for enemies not to benefit from the decreased charge time. If that's an issue, you can always make a duplicate spell and add it to yourself via the console.

Comment: Good idea! I thought of duplicates, but blanked on how to add them to the player.

Comment: Is it possible to create a magic effect that will reduce the cast time of all spells? Because that solution, if it exists, would be better then editing spells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same magic in both hands, this will increase the damage of your spell. Depending on what magic you use this can either allow you to cast with another animation or use the spell twice as fast.

Usually the damage vs mana cost is worse than using different spells in each hand.

Otherwise I think it is not possible to increase your casting speed.

Comment: The damage/mana ratio is *always* worse when dual casting.DPS and stagger effect are why people use it. I think charging takes the same time. "only 10% damage increase for 40% higher Magicka cost." - [Skill Usage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction#Skill_Usage)